# Python - DF to DB using SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas, iteration

I would like some help with the following:

I have a working process that reads a CSV, changes a few formats, puts it into a DF and then inserts into a table on SAP HANA through a sql query (using chunks and tuples).

Now I need to modify this code to, instead of reading a CSV, inserting a DF directly to HANA, with the same criteria (using chunks and tuples).

I tried with no success modifying the first line (with pd.read_csv...) of code with:

```
chuncksize = 10**5

for i, piece in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // chuncksize):
    out_df_reformed = tuple(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
    length = len(out_df_reformed[0])
    elem = [":"+ str(x+1) for x in range(len(out_df_reformed[0]))]
    params = ",".join(elem)
    sql = f'INSERT INTO {user}."{table}" VALUES (%s)' %(params)
    cursor.executemany(sql,out_df_reformed)
```

I get the error: `ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length`

**Current code (read_csv)**

```
chuncksize = 10**5

with pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=chuncksize,sep = sepp, engine='python', dtype=str, keep_default_na=False, encoding= 'latin1') as reader:
    for chunk in reader:
        df = pd.DataFrame(chunk)
        out_df_reformed = tuple(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
        length = len(out_df_reformed[0])
        elem = [":"+ str(x+1) for x in range(len(out_df_reformed[0]))]
        params = ",".join(elem)
        sql = f'INSERT INTO {user}."{table}" VALUES (%s)' %(params)
        cursor.executemany(sql,out_df_reformed)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why aren't you using `to_sql` with SQLAlchemy? If you don't process the dataframe in any way though, it would be a *lot* faster to import the CSV directly into the database, eg using IMPORT. 100K rows isn't a lot but trying to execute 100K INSERTS one by one is way too slow.

Comment: Does SQLAlchemy works with HDBCLI (HANA)? Also my df has ~6mil rows.

Comment: Why are you going through Pandas at all then? Why not use IMPORT?

Comment: I have to change several formats, rename and drop a few columns and filter some results before inserting into hana.

Comment: SAP itself [provides HANA support for SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/SAP/sqlalchemy-hana)